# Center link text in <li> tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an image and text both with links inside of a `<li>` tag. The `<ul>` is styled to create columns out of the images and content.

**Question: How do I center the copy under the image and add a small margin below the image to give it some separation?**

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="display-posts-listing">
    <li class="listing-item one-fourth first">
        <a class="image" href="http://websitex.com/sept-15-2014/">
        <a class="title" href="http://websitex.com/sept-15-2014/">Sept 15, 2014</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul.display-posts-listing li img{display:block;margin:0px auto;}
ul.display-posts-listing li a.title{margin:0px auto;font:bold 14px arial;margin-top:30px;color:white;text-decoration:none;}
ul.display-posts-listing li a.title:hover{color:orange;}
```

Comment: Your html seems to be missing an `<img />` tag, yet one is referenced in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both your HTML aqnd CSS are weird, change it to this:

```
<div class="container mainbody">
    <ul class="display-posts-listing">
<li class="listing-item one-fourth first">
    <img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrkwY.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="" />
<a class="title" href="http://websitex.com/sept-15-2014/">Sept 15, 2014</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and CSS to something like this:

```
ul{width:200px;}
ul{width:200px; text-align:center; list-style-type:none}
li img{display:block;margin:0px auto; margin-bottom:20px;}
ul li a{margin:0px auto;font:bold 14px arial;margin-top:30px;color:#f00;text-decoration:none;}
ul.display-posts-listing li a.title:hover{color:orange;}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pdvk6c2w/)

Comment: Fabio I agree the html this plugin creates is weird but I didnt want to set the ul width because I want to keep it fluid. when I added the margin-top to the ul li a I am not seeing the space.

Comment: Actually adding the margin-bottom to the image instead of margin-top to the text did work thanks.

Comment: what I meant with weird is you didn't actually have an image, I have added a width to the UL for visualization purposes, but you can have any width you want

Answer (score 2):

In order to center text try using the following CSS code.

```
text-align:center
```

Adding margin to the bottom of the image should give you the separation you're seeking. Alternately the margin-bottom property can be used.

```
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
```

example:

```
ul.display-posts-listing li .img{display:block;margin: 0 0 10px 0;}
ul.display-posts-listing li a.title{margin:0px auto;font:bold 14px arial;margin-top:30px;color:white;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i note you use

```
<a class="image" href="http://websitex.com/sept-15-2014/">
```

in this way i think your css code should be   a.image

```
ul.display-posts-listing li a.image{display:block;margin:0px auto;}
```

or also,, make big `<li>` with `position:relative`  and text  `position:absolute;`

you can control it's position by ex: `top:10px;right:10px;`   and other side